# git: propagating local commit in one branch to another

Tags: git

im not sure if i have the terminology correct but i have a git workspace which has one commit

```
(workspace1)$ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mainline' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

(workspace1)$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://git.company.com:2222/pkg/ServiceA
```

i want to take the commit in this branch (workspace1) to another workspace (workspace2) which is synced to mainline

```
(workspace2) $ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mainline'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

(workspace2)$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://git.company.com:2222/pkg/ServiceA
```

basically i want to make a change off of the change i made in workspace1 (in another workspace) but i dont want to be blocked on it while the change in workspace1 is being code reviewed

im not too familiar with git but i think another way of being unblocked is that just keep making changes in workspace1 but branch the new changes if i need to address some code comments in the original commit then commit that change and apply back the branch i was working off of?

Comment: Side note on the terminology: by *workspace* I think you really mean *repository*. However, since 2.5, Git has the ability to add a work-tree to an existing repository, using `git worktree add`. If you mean *work-tree*, and you have two separate work-trees using one underlying repository, the best answer changes.

Comment: Doesn’t cherry pick do precisely that?

Comment: @torek ah okay that make sense. whenever i am refering to a workspace, i am thinking of a directory in a file system. i assume worktree could be a subdirectory?

Comment: A work-tree is a directory, yes, but there's more to it. In general, the *top level* of some work-tree contains either a `.git` directory that contains the repository proper, or a `.git` file that contains the path name of the `.git` directory that contains the repository. The indirection exists to support both added work-trees and the modern layout for submodules (the old layout was to just have the `.git` directory for the sub-repository at the same level as the work-tree for the sub-repository).

Comment: The repository itself (`.git/`) contains one *index* per work-tree, one `HEAD` per work-tree, and a few other per-worktree files.  The layout of these is a little weird due to the lack of added work-trees pre-2.5. The index is essentially the data structure from which Git makes *new* commits, plus information about the indexed work-tree to speed up `git status` and other Git operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece of cake.

```
// In workspace 1:
$ git checkout -b ealeon-branch  # Create a new branch for yourself.
$ git push -u origin eleaon-branch  # Push the branch to origin.

// In workspace 2:
$ git fetch  # Update remote info so it knows about your new branch.
$ git checkout eleaon-branch  # Checkout the branch you pushed.
```

You can open a PR from eleaon-branch to wherever you want your code to be merged. If you make additional changes in workspace 1, you can push those up and then pull them down (merge them into) workspace 2.

Comment: i ended up just using the same workspace and stashing new changes